# Garage door won't close all the way even when disconnected from the opener

Tags: garage-door

My garage door has a 1/2 inch gap when it's closed completely. When I disconnect the J-Bar from the door, the door still maintains the gap (removing the opener as a variable)

(I don't know anything about garage doors, but here's what I observed)

- There appears to be additional cable on the Cable Drum. I don't think it's "running out" of cable and stopping early.
- I don't see anything on the ground that would prevent it from closing all the way.

Thanks.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/82915/manual-garage-door-wont-fully-close?rq=1

Comment: Have you tried the tips at the question you've linked? If so, [edit] your question, include the link _there_ and tell us that you've tried these things and it hasn't solved your problem, otherwise, you've probably done us the favor of doing the research to find the duplicate so we can close this question. While you're editing, please include some pics of the door, springs, cables, etc. Make sure they're well lit, focused and we can tell what we're looking at. Odds are good that there's nothing _you_ can see, but that someone else might see.

Comment: Does the top of the door press firmly against the header?  Check the rails for lose bolts.

Comment: If you can't see what's binding or impeding travel, neither can we. Post some clear, well-lit photos or look closer. It shouldn't be hard to find the problem, then you can ask about solutions.

Comment: It's possible that the springs are too tight.  They could have too much tension.  That will make the door rise slightly.